# Replace string containing $& in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace a html string with a dynamic value.This dynamic value(HTML encode) is to replace a pattern in the html string.

```
var htmlstring = "<div>{NAME}</div>";
var name = "$&lt;Anonymous&gt;"  //Encoded form of "$<Anonymous>";
html = htmlstring.replace(/{NAME}/g,name);
```

I need to get **"$<Anonymous>"** as output but i get **"{NAME}lt;Anonymous>"** as output.This is because "$&" matches the whole match "{NAME}" and replace "$&" with "{NAME}".

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 9):

From Docs of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), `$&` Inserts the matched substring.

[image]

You can use the replace callback to get the `$&` literal in the replaced string.

```js
var htmlstring = "<div>{NAME}</div>";
var name = "$&lt;Anonymous&gt;" //Encoded form of "$<Annonymous>";
var html = htmlstring.replace(/{NAME}/g, function(m) {
  return name;
});

console.log(html);
document.write(html);
```

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, to replace with `$`, you need to escape the dollar symbol with another dollar symbol, otherwise, `$&` is treated as a backreference to the whole matched value (i.e. `{NAME}` here).

You need to use

```
var name = "$$&lt;Anonymous&gt;"
            ^^
```

```js
var htmlstring = "<div>{NAME}</div>";
var name = "$$&lt;Anonymous&gt;"  //Encoded form of "$<Annonymous>";
html = htmlstring.replace(/{NAME}/g,name);
document.write(html);
```

See [`String#replace` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> **Pattern Inserts**
>   **`$$`**        Inserts a "$".
>   **`$&`**        Inserts the matched substring.