# Escape RegExp.lastMatch ($&) in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, literals

I have an `input` box which the user types text into. I'm using the inputted text and replacing a portion of a large text file.

The problem is, if the user inputs the `$&` characters it will result in a [**lastMatch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch) instead of the literal text which is of course a dollar sign (`$`) followed by an ampersand (`&`) without any special meaning.

You can see the user input here:

[image: user input]

To simulate the user input, I wrote the following code:

```js
var originalString = "# Mandatory parameter\n#EPCDatabase/EPCdatabase.param/epc.db.user=\n# Mandatory parameter";

var regexExpression = new RegExp('#EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=.*$', "im");
var replaceSting = "EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=test#$#%^%>$&<%(*"
var newPropertiesText = originalString.replace(regexExpression, replaceSting);

console.log(originalString);
console.log(newPropertiesText);
```

The problem is that instead of appending the `$&` literally, it will append the lastMatch, and the `newPropertiesText` created as follows:

[image: last match]

[As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040338/replace-string-containing-in-javascript-regex), I've tried escaping the `$` with two `$$`, so it will mean a literal dollar instead of the special combination:

```
"EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=aaaa#$#%^%>$&<%(*".replace(/\$&/g, '$$&');
                                   here is the problem  ^^
```

But that didn't help, so I tried different combination of `\\$\\$` and similar patterns. But I couldn't send to the regex a simple `$&` literal.

**EDIT:**
Using this `escape` function didn't solve the issue:

```js
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var originalString = "# Mandatory parameter\n#EPCDatabase/EPCdatabase.param/epc.db.user=\n# Mandatory parameter";

var regexExpression = new RegExp('#EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=.*$', "im");
var replaceSting = RegExp.escape("EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=aaaa#$#%^%>$&<%(*");
var newPropertiesText = originalString.replace(regexExpression, replaceSting);
console.log(originalString);
console.log(newPropertiesText);
```

You can see it still returns the `lastMatch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @Laurel please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after additional reading, thinking, some tries and additional `#FFFFFF` hairs, I got what it takes to solve this issue.

In order to tell the regex to put a literal `$&` instead of the `entire match`, you'll have to use the following:

`.replace(/\$&/, '$$$$&')`

`$$` tells the regex engine one literal dollar sign, `$$$$` tells it two literal dollar signs -> and two literal dollar signs one after the other in the replacement string actually become one literal dollar sign `$`.
Followed by an `&` its become a normal literal `$&` without `last match` meaning.

```js
var originalString = "# Mandatory parameter\n#EPCDatabase/EPCdatabase.param/epc.db.user=\n# Mandatory parameter";

var regexExpression = new RegExp('#EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=.*$', "im");
var replaceSting = "EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=aaaa#$#%^%>$&<%(*".replace(/\$&/, '$$$$&');
var newPropertiesText = originalString.replace(regexExpression, replaceSting);
console.log(originalString);
console.log(newPropertiesText);
```

You can [view the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/Alon_A/mu52du8s/2/) if you want to play with it.

Comment: Thanks for following up by answering your own question, this certainly saved me some `#FFFFFF` hairs!