# Why str.replace() behave strangely when replacement string has regex in it?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
let a =  `<script crossOrigin="anonymous" src="//example.com/index.js"></script>`

let regex = new RegExp(
            `<script(.*?) src="` + '//example.com/index.js' + `"></script>`, 'g')
let replacementString = 'document.cookie=e.replace(/[^+#$&^`|]/g,encodeURIComponent).replace("(","%28").replace(")","%29")+"="+t.replace(/[^+#$&\/:<-\[\]-}]/g,encodeURIComponent)+(r.domain?";domain="+r.domain:"")+(r.path?";path="+r.path:"")+(r.secure?";secure":"")+(r.httponly?";HttpOnly":"")'
b = a.replace(regex, replacementString)
```

The `b` result is:

```
document.cookie=e.replace(/[^+#<script crossOrigin="anonymous" src="//example.com/index.js"></script>^`|]/g,encodeURIComponent).replace("(","%28").replace(")","%29")+"="+t.replace(/[^+#<script crossOrigin="anonymous" src="//example.com/index.js"></script>/:<-[]-}]/g,encodeURIComponent)+(r.domain?";domain="+r.domain:"")+(r.path?";path="+r.path:"")+(r.secure?";secure":"")+(r.httponly?";HttpOnly":"")
```

while the expected result is the `replacementString` value as is.

Why is the result different?

Comment: You need to escape the `replacementString` before passing it into the `a.replace()` You may find this post useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- `$&` is a backreference to the whole match value in JS replacement pattern, use `$$&` instead of `$&` (see [Replace string containing $& in JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040338))
- `.` in `index.js` is not escaped. Use `'//example.com/index\\.js'` instead of `'//example.com/index.js'` (see [Regular Expression to match a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640) and [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066))

JS fixed snippet:

```js
let a = '<script crossOrigin="anonymous" src="//example.com/index.js"></scrpit>';

let regex = new RegExp(
            '<script(.*?) src="' + '//example.com/index.js' + '"></scrpit>', 'g');
let replacementString = 'document.cookie=e.replace(/[^+#$$&^`|]/g,encodeURIComponent).replace("(","%28").replace(")","%29")+"="+t.replace(/[^+#$$&\/:<-\[\]-}]/g,encodeURIComponent)+(r.domain?";domain="+r.domain:"")+(r.path?";path="+r.path:"")+(r.secure?";secure":"")+(r.httponly?";HttpOnly":"")';
let b = a.replace(regex, replacementString);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + b + "</pre>";
```