# How to sanitize/replace $& (dollar + ampersand) in a JS string that cannot be escaped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, special-characters, currency

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040338/replace-string-containing-in-javascript-regex) question, but the answers **don't** solve my problem.

Backend (Node.js) receives some HTML from the frontend (React):

```js
// this is merely an example
const price = '<strong>US$&nbsp;0.99</strong>';
```

The currency format is taken from [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). See this bit - `$&`? We'll come back to that later.

In the code below, `#orderPrice#` will be replaced with the product's price HTML and the string will be sent via e-mail, which comes from a template:

```js
const template = `Your order has a total price of #orderPrice#.`.

const email = template.replace('#orderPrice#', price);
```

All fine and dandy, except it isn't. As seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch) and in the aforementioned SO question, `$&` has special meaning when replacing strings - it inserts the matching string, despite being considered non-standard.

Let's say we have `string1.replace(/pattern/g, string2)`. What caught me off guard is that **neither `string1` nor `string2`** can be sanitized/stripped off the `$&` bit, so I can't even sanitize the price html before inserting it into the template. The only way I can see it working is escaping the `$` as `$$` from the start, which is not possible due to the use of `Number.toLocaleString()`. We can always drop the `.toLocaleString()` and hardcode `US$$` as a workaround, but that doesn't really address the question itself.

All that said, how can I sanitize a string having `$&`, assuming I can't escape it when it's being written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```js
const email = template.replace('#orderPrice#', () => price);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double any `$` characters in `price`.

```js
const price = '<strong>US$&nbsp;0.99</strong>';
const template = `Your order has a total price of #orderPrice#.`;
const email = template.replace('#orderPrice#', price.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$'));
console.log(email);
```

Comment: Another option is `const email = template.replace('#orderPrice#', () => price);`

Comment: Thank you both for replying. @thorn0, can you post your comment as an answer? Both solutions work, but yours is a little more elegant and it's the one I'm picking.